# Checking if user is authenticated or guest without @Guest

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to ask, if there's any way to check if a user is authenticated to the website and differentiate them with the guest without using any @Guest directive? Let's say, I still want to do checking with the Auth::user method, without triggering the "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" error.

Comment: what about ```if( empty(Auth::user()) ) { ... } ``` ?

Comment: `if (Auth::user())` is enough to tell if there's a user connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

in that case, u can add a field in the user table and use it as a flag, like user_type: 'guest|employee', and the correct syntax of using auth Auth::user()->id